# How to remove TextMate plugin

Tags: textmate

I install viMate (a vi keybinding plugin for TextMate) but now I want to remove it from my TextMate. I tried reinstalling TextMate but it didn't work. Can someone help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this. Found the plugin folder under ~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/PlugIns and deleted it.